# Issue with starting Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I have been trying to install and start Impala on a native Hadoop installation. Below is the error log using `impalad`. Impala server sits on Secondary Name Node (nn02.tcs.com)

```
[root@nn02 impala]# impalad
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
E0903 23:43:52.400326 21972 impala-server.cc:208] Could not read the HDFS root directory at hdfs://nn01.tcs.com:8020. Error was: 
    Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 
        Message missing required fields: callId, status; 
        Host Details : local host is: "nn02.tcs.com/192.168.2.101"; 
        destination host is: "nn01.tcs.com":8020; 
E0903 23:43:52.400411 21972 impala-server.cc:210] Aborting Impala Server startup due to improper configuration
```

I can access the same HDFS through:

```
[root@nn02 impala]# hadoop fs -ls hdfs://nn01.tcs.com
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs       9737 2014-06-16 09:27 hdfs://nn01.tcs.com/user/root/x
```

I am able to access the site in Name Node (nn01.tcs.com) through browser in Name Node:

http://nn01.tcs.com:8020 - and I get the below message

> It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port.
>   This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon.

**Please help resolve this error**

Comment: The `InvalidProtocolBufferException` makes me think you may have a version mismatch. What version of Impala and what version of HDFS are you running?

Comment: Version Details:   Impala Version - impalad version 1.4.0-cdh4-INTERNAL                   Hadoop 2.4.0.2.1.2.1-471

Comment: What output do you get when you give `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://nn01.tcs.com:8020` in command line

Answer (score -1):

Change
/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://nn01.tcs.com:8020</value>
</property>
```

To

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://nn01.tcs.com:8020/</value>
</property>
                                 ^end slash is needed
```